# PostgreSQL query to fetch data every day from 10 pm tonite to 6 am next day

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I am new to PostgreSQL(timescaleDB) and writing the time series queries for my application.

**I am having a situation where I have to fetch the data for a selected time frame say (10 am to 6 pm) every day for a date range say (1st Dec to 26th Dec).**

Below is my query to do this.

```
select
    time_bucket('1 day',
    device_time at time zone 'Asia/Kolkata') as device_timestamp,
    round(cast(last(active_energy_delivered_kwh, device_time) - first(active_energy_delivered_kwh, device_time) as numeric), 2) as kwh
from
    schneider_new
where
    meter_id in ('s3')
    and device_time::date between date '2018-12-01' and date '2018-12-26'
    and device_time::time between time '10:00:00' and time '18:00:00'
group by
    device_timestamp
```

The above query is working fine and I am getting the proper data as I wanted.

Now, I want to fetch the data from `10 pm tonight to 6 am tomorrow`.
As I am grouping the results by `device_timestamp` i.e a day wise, it is not possible for me to get the data from `10 pm to 6 am` using this query.

I tried a lot of things to make it work, but none of the solutions worked.

Please help me to know the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

`device_time between (current_date + '22:00'::time) and (current_date + 1 + '06:00'::time`)